# ReactJS - Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing an error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

The code is as:

```js
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._updateLocalStorage();

    if (this.state.searchValue !== "") {
      this.setState({
        filteredNotes: this.state.notes.filter(
          note =>
            note.text
              .toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(this.state.searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        )
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        filteredNotes: this.state.notes 
      });
    }
  }
```

[image: Maximum Update Depth Exceeded Error]

Comment: Hi, need any help? Cause I just saw you undo the accept, feel free to make an update if there are further problems you are facing.

Comment: @keikai It was working but when I make the changes it is not being reflected instantly. Only I have to refresh the browser each time the change is done. So I think I am stuck there.

Comment: State update is async, there is another fault inside your code but I'm sure it's not related with this one. Check the document: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be fixed by putting empty comparison if both the states are equal before the main state call. Also, I made a change in the else condition.

```js
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    this._updateLocalStorage();

    if (this.state.searchValue !== "") {
      this.setState({
        filteredNotes: this.state.notes.filter(
          note =>
            note.text
              .toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(this.state.searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        )
      });
    } else if(prevState.filteredNotes === this.state.filteredNotes) {
      //do nothing
    } else if(this.state.searchValue === "") {
      this.setState({
        filteredNotes: this.state.notes 
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The **componentDidUpdate** would be called every time if there is a state change.

So you may need to use `setState` inside with caution.

---

Strict your condition for those `setState`. Perhaps something like below:

Some Notice Points:

- object comparison
- value/address reference

```
componentDidUpdate(pervProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.filteredNotes !== this.state.filteredNotes) {
    this._updateLocalStorage();
    if (this.state.searchValue !== "") {
      this.setState({
        filteredNotes: this.state.notes.filter(
          note =>
            note.text
              .toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(this.state.searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        )
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        filteredNotes: this.state.notes 
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what is happening:

1. in CDM once `this.state.searchValue` gets truthy - it updates state
2. update on state trigger anothe CDM
3. step 1. repeats
4. step 2. repeats
5. endless updates...

What should you do:

1. update CDU to this `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`
2. update your conditionall to:

```
if(this.state.searchValue !== "" && this.state.searchValue !== prevState.searchValue) {...}
```